# Why isn't it trivial to create a virtual integer timestamp column from a TIMESTAMP column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, cast, integer

There's no way to extract an integer timestamp from a `TIMESTAMP` column in a virtual column context in MySQL because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is not allowed in virtual columns. Why isn't this a trivial task?

Comment: Please show us your attempt, together with the error message provided.

Answer (score 2):

A generated column, virtual or not, [permits only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) "[l]iterals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators"; `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is *not* deterministic, [because](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) it "interprets ***date*** as a value in the session time zone", which obviously can change from session to session.

In other words, it is trivially not possible.

Comment: The result of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on a `TIMESTAMP` field is deterministic. A `TIMESTAMP` is stored internally as a Unix epoch timestamp. I just want to get that value.

Comment: @Dan There exists a case when the function is not deterministic. This is enough for to eject the attempt to use it it generated column expression.